# docker circular reference error

Tags: spring, docker

So when I am running my spring project directly from IntelliJ it all works, but when I deployed project with docker container and try to run it I got:

```
Error creating bean with name 'passwordEncoder': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

Is it common issue ? I did not find any solution..

Comment: That error message is not from Docker, is your app. Probably the image is missing something. Can you post your Dockerfile?

Comment: I rebuilt my project to avoid circular reference, so it's solved this way..